# Why does regularity of an ordinal $\gamma$ imply the existence of a sequence $(\delta_n)$ such that $\delta_n<\gamma$ for all $n$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

**Source**: *Set Theory* by Kenneth Kunen.

**Lemma III.6.2**: Let $\gamma$ be any limit ordinal, and assume that $\kappa:=cf(\gamma)>\omega$. Then the intersection of any family of fewer than $\kappa$ club subsets of $\gamma$ is club.

**Proof**: Fix clubs $C_{\xi}\subseteq\gamma$ for $\xi<\lambda$, and let $D=\underset{\xi}{\bigcap}C_{\xi}$. Every intersection of closed set is closed, but we must show that $D$ is unbounded, assuming that $\lambda<\kappa$. So, fixed $\delta_0<\gamma$; we shall prove that $\sup(D)>\delta_0$.

First, for $\xi<\lambda$, define $f_{\xi}: \gamma\to\gamma$ so that $f_{\xi}(\alpha)$ is the least ordinal in $C_{\xi}$ that is greater than $\alpha$. Then, by recursion on $n$, define $\delta_n<\gamma$ so that $\delta_{n+1}=\sup\{f_{\xi}(\delta_n): \xi<\lambda\}$; **note that $\mathbf{\delta_{n+1}<\gamma}$ because $\mathbf{cf(\gamma)>\lambda}$**.

**My Question**: I am stuck on the boldface text. I've shown that $\delta_{n+1}\subseteq\gamma$, therefore $\delta_{n+1}\leq\gamma$. But how does $cf(\gamma)>\lambda$ imply $\delta_{n+1}\neq\gamma$? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $\delta_{n+1}=\gamma$, then there is a subset of $\gamma$ of cardinality $\leq\lambda$ whose supremum is $\gamma$...

Comment: Shouldn't it be clubs $C_{\xi} \subseteq \gamma$ for $\xi \lt \kappa$?

Comment: @RobertShore Actually, I think it should be $\xi<\lambda$ (with $\lambda<\kappa$ - we want *fewer* than $\kappa$-many clubs).

Comment: @AlexKruckman I actually tried to arrive at that contradiction with the exact same approach, but then I realize: isn't $\sup\{f_{\xi}(\delta_n): \xi<\lambda\}$ defined to be $\underset{\xi<\lambda}{\bigcup}f_{\xi}(\delta_n)$, where each $f_{\xi}(\delta_n)$ is an ordinal? Then I can't really say $\delta_{n+1}$ has cardinality $<\lambda$ just because $\xi<\lambda$ is in the set builder...

Comment: It's not $\delta_{n+1}$ that has cardinality $\leq \lambda$, it's the set $\{f_\xi(\delta_n):\xi<\lambda\}$. Do you know the definition of cofinality?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Ahh I see-that is embarrassing. I do, it should be the smallest cardinality of a cofinal subset, where a cofinal subset is a subset $A\subseteq\gamma$ such that $\forall x\in\gamma\exists y\in A (x\leq y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose for contradiction that $\delta_{n+1} = \gamma$. Then $\sup\{f_\xi(\delta_n):\xi<\lambda\} = \gamma$, so $X_{n+1} = \{f_\xi(\delta_n):\xi<\lambda\}$ is cofinal in $\gamma$. Since $|X_{n+1}|\leq \lambda$ (since the map $\xi\mapsto f_\xi(\delta_n)$ is a surjective function $\lambda\to X_{n+1}$), this implies $\mathrm{cf}(\gamma)\leq \lambda$, contradicting the hypothesis that $\lambda<\kappa = \mathrm{cf}(\gamma)$.